# Hyperlink changes address when opening

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

Hyperlink im Excel data:
HTTPS://apply.d.co.uk/JobDetail/9467
But when I click on it, the address is:
HTTPS://apply.d.co.uk/Error

I tried checking whether the URL is correct and it always says yes but when I open it, it changes and shows Error in the address.

I used the function:

```
Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function
```

I just need a solution so that I don't need to open each hyperlink to check if it shows the error.

//////
The solution from taller below works!
[image]

Comment: I don't want You to open the links. These are work related and have been modified to show the example of the issue im having.

Comment: Even if that is the case, your problem does not appear to be about programming, unless you want to test each hyperlink ... in which case please state that, and also share what research you've done and what code you've attempted so far.

Comment: *I tried checking whether the URL is correct* - how did you do that ?

Comment: I used a function found on stackoverflow:Function URLExists(url As String) As Boolean
    Dim Request As Object
    Dim ff As Integer
    Dim rc As Variant

    On Error GoTo EndNow
    Set Request = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    With Request
      .Open "GET", url, False
      .Send
      rc = .StatusText
    End With
    Set Request = Nothing
    If rc = "OK" Then URLExists = True

    Exit Function
EndNow:
End Function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CheckConn` returns an [HTTP status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) and redirected URL. HTTP status code will be 0 if the URL is not accessible.

```vb
Public Function CheckConn(sURL) As String
    Const WHR_EnableRedirects = 6
    Const WHR_URL = 1
    Dim oXmlHttp As Object, nRetVal As Integer
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXmlHttp = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
    oXmlHttp.Option(WHR_EnableRedirects) = True
    oXmlHttp.Open "HEAD", sURL, False
    oXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
    oXmlHttp.send ""
    nRetVal = oXmlHttp.Status
    CheckConn = "Status: " & nRetVal & ", Redirect URL:" & oXmlHttp.Option(WHR_URL)
    Set oXmlHttp = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
Sub demo()
    Dim sU As String
    sU = "HTTPS://apply.d.co.uk/JobDetail/9467"
    Debug.Print (CheckConn(sU))
    sU = "https://www.youtube.com/shorts/w3-yM1IjuB0"
    Debug.Print (CheckConn(sU))
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it shows "200" for both sites. The issue is that the hyperlink opens but the address changes from "JobDetail/9467" to "Error"

Comment: I can't access your url. It returns 0 on my pc. So I can't tracce how it changed to Error.

Comment: Is it possibile to add a line to the code that would return its address? Eg. You check if the URL is valid: https://www.google.com/ and then it returns "200" and the address? (This should be the same in that case but in my case it will show the one with error Word)

Comment: Yes. I have updated the code.

Comment: Is there a way to get the final address?  When opening some of internal sites first the link ends with "/Login" but then it automatically logs in and shows either "JobDetail/1946" (which is correct) or again "/Error" and I need that final address. But the function returns only the "/Login" part which is the initial address.

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the final url. I guess it is not `redirect`.